# What is this lyric's English Translation from Tony Marshall's Schöne Maid

Tags: german-to-english, lyrics

In Tony Marshall's 1971 hit song Schöne Maid he sings the lyrics, "Schöne Maid 
Glaub mir so jung wie heut"

I understand that song lyrics might not make sense even to native speakers.

Is there a better translation than, "Pretty girl believe me so young like the day"?

Also, I am new to this forum, and if this question is not appropriate or is too informal for german.stackExchange would you please tell me a more appropriate forum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Schöne Maid, glaub mir, so jung wie heut* is not a full German sentence. The full lyrics go *Schöne Maid, glaub mir, so jung wie heut kommen wir nicht mehr zusammen.* I do not know the song, but the lyrics I found suggest that this sentence is split across multiple musical verses. Maybe this is the reason why you didn't relate the two parts.

*So jung wie heut kommen wir nicht mehr zusammen* is a pretty common German figure of speech translating to something like *we will never meet again as young as we are today*.

Comment: [The lyrics](https://www.golyr.de/tony-marshall/songtext-schoene-maid-44605.html) do in fact continue like this: "Schöne Maid, glaub' mir, so jung wie heut' / Oh ja ho ja ho / Kommen wir nicht mehr zusammen, vielleicht /
Ist es schon morgen viel zu spät". The phrase "So jung kommen wir nicht mehr zusammen" is typically used as an invitation to nudge somebody into something: "You only live once, so drink with me, or dance with me, or.. - who knows if we'll get another chance"